MacOS Automator Resize and Position VSCode Window with AppleScript
Working with AppleScript to size and position various application windows is great when it works but VSCode seems to be posing a challenge. I'm a complete n00b to AppleScript but here is what I have so far. Is there a better way to adjust window placement?
use scripting additions

global CONFIG_COLUMNS, CONFIG_ROWS
global SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH
global SIZE_COLUMN, SIZE_ROW

on arrange(appName, offsetX, offsetY, width, height)
    if offsetX is greater than CONFIG_COLUMNS or offsetX is less than 0 then error "Invalid offsetX for " & appName
    if offsetY is greater than CONFIG_ROWS or offsetY is less than 0 then error "Invalid offsetY for " & appName
    if offsetX + width is greater than CONFIG_COLUMNS then error "Config for " & appName & " would extend beyond the screen"
    if offsetY + height is greater than CONFIG_ROWS then error "Config for " & appName & " would extend beyond the screen"
    
    set OFFSET_LEFT to round SIZE_COLUMN * offsetX rounding down
    set OFFSET_TOP to round SIZE_ROW * offsetY rounding down
    set OFFSET_RIGHT to round SIZE_COLUMN * width rounding down
    set OFFSET_BOTTOM to round SIZE_ROW * height rounding down
    set POS to {OFFSET_LEFT, OFFSET_TOP, OFFSET_RIGHT, OFFSET_BOTTOM}
    
    try
        tell application appName
            set bounds of windows to {OFFSET_LEFT, OFFSET_TOP, OFFSET_LEFT + OFFSET_RIGHT, OFFSET_TOP + OFFSET_BOTTOM}
        end tell
    on error
        try
            tell application "System Events"
                set targetWindow to first window of application process appName
                
                set position of targetWindow to {OFFSET_LEFT, OFFSET_TOP}
                set size of targetWindow to {OFFSET_RIGHT, OFFSET_BOTTOM}
            end tell
        on error message
            log message
        end try
    end try
end arrange

on run
    set CONFIG_COLUMNS to 12
    set CONFIG_ROWS to 6
    
    tell application "Finder"
        set {0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT} to bounds of window of desktop
        set SIZE_COLUMN to SCREEN_WIDTH / CONFIG_COLUMNS
        set SIZE_ROW to SCREEN_HEIGHT / CONFIG_ROWS
    end tell
    
    -- arrange("Automator", 4, 0, 6, 6)
    arrange("Firefox", 0, 0, 6, 6)
    arrange("Music", 4, 3, 3, 3)
    arrange("Script Editor", 4, 1, 4, 4)
    arrange("Visual Studio Code", 4, 0, 6, 6)
end run

The latest code is available here - https://kalisjoshua.me/articles/arranging-windows.html.
